# How to shortcut complicated API access (v8)

Tags: c++, api, macros, inline

everytime I want to get a C compatible value from an v8:Object I have to do following:

```
Local<Object> obj = args[0]->ToObject();

obj->Get(String::New("property"))->NumberValue();
```

To shortcut this I could use a helper:

```
obj->Get(strg("property"))->NumberValue();

Local<Value> strg(const char* str) {
    return String::New(str);
}
```

But this is not a real improvement. Does C(++) provide a tool for this use-case (macros?) ?

If yes how would it look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
#define PROPERTY(object, name) \
  object->Get(String::New(name))
```

Usage:

```
Local<Object> obj = args[0]->ToObject();

PROPERTY(obj, "property")->NumberValue();
```

Can even do additional shortcut:

```
#define NUMBER_VALUE(object, name) \
  PROPERTY(object, name)->NumberValue()
```

Usage:

```
Local<Object> obj = args[0]->ToObject();

NUMBER_VALUE(obj, "property");
```